# pusher is not displaying notification on page in laravel

Tags: php, html, jquery, laravel, pusher

Started to make notification using laravel with pusher, event is send to pusher and recieving event, Everything is working properly only notification is not displaying on page, Here is my event code

```
<?php
namespace App\Events;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
class EnquiryPickup implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;
    public $username;
    public $message;
    public function __construct($username)
    {
        $this->username = $username;
        $this->message  = "{$username} send you Enquiry Pickup";
    }
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return ['enquiry-pickup'];
    }
}
```

Config of broadcasting code is here

```
'connections' => [
        'pusher' => [
            'driver' => 'pusher',
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'options' => [
                'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
                'useTLS' => true,
            ]
        ],
```

Now event is firing withing route

```
Route::get('broadcast',function(){
     event( new  \App\Events\EnquiryPickup('vikas'));
     return "event is created";
});
```

And here is trying to display notification on welcome blade

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Demo Application</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/bootstrap-notifications.min.css">
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-9" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Demo App</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="dropdown dropdown-notifications">
                    <a href="#notifications-panel" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                        <i data-count="0" class="glyphicon glyphicon-bell notification-icon"></i>
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-container">
                        <div class="dropdown-toolbar">
                            <div class="dropdown-toolbar-actions">
                                <a href="#">Mark all as read</a>
                            </div>
                            <h3 class="dropdown-toolbar-title">Notifications (<span class="notif-count">0</span>)</h3>
                        </div>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        </ul>
                        <div class="dropdown-footer text-center">
                            <a href="#">View All</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//js.pusher.com/3.1/pusher.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var notificationsWrapper   = $('.dropdown-notifications');
    var notificationsToggle    = notificationsWrapper.find('a[data-toggle]');
    var notificationsCountElem = notificationsToggle.find('i[data-count]');
    var notificationsCount     = parseInt(notificationsCountElem.data('count'));
    var notifications          = notificationsWrapper.find('ul.dropdown-menu');
    if (notificationsCount <= 0) {
       notificationsWrapper.hide();
   }
    Pusher.logToConsole = true;
    var pusher = new Pusher("{{ env('PUSHER_APP_KEY') }}", {
        cluster: 'ap2',
        encryption:true,
    });
    var channel = pusher.subscribe('subscribed');
    channel.bind('pusher:subscription_succeeded', function(members) {
        console.log('subscribed successful') ;
    });
    channel.bind('pusher:subscription_error', function(status) {
        console.log('subscribed error: '+ status) ;
    });
    var channel = pusher.subscribe('enquiry-pickup');
    channel.bind('\\App\\Events\\EnquiryPickup', function(data) {
        var existingNotifications = notifications.html();
        var avatar = Math.floor(Math.random() * (71 - 20 + 1)) + 20;
        var newNotificationHtml = `
          <li class="notification active">
              <div class="media">
                <div class="media-left">
                  <div class="media-object">
                    <img src="https://api.adorable.io/avatars/71/`+avatar+`.png" class="img-circle" alt="50x50" style="width: 50px; height: 50px;">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="media-body">
                  <strong class="notification-title">`+data.message+`</strong>
                  <div class="notification-meta">
                    <small class="timestamp">about a minute ago</small>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
          </li>
        `;
        notifications.html(newNotificationHtml + existingNotifications);
        notificationsCount += 1;
        notificationsCountElem.attr('data-count', notificationsCount);
        notificationsWrapper.find('.notif-count').text(notificationsCount);
        notificationsWrapper.show();
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Only getting error

> No callbacks on enquiry-pickup for pusher:subscription_succeeded

Can someone help me out what i am doing wrong ?, search every where but not getting any solution.